# Facebook Login not working if official app's installed

Tags: facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to set up Facebook in my android app but I had a problem and even the samples didn't work ! Then I tried again on different devices and I just figured out the samples only work on devices which **do not have official facebook app installed**. It seemed to me completely illogical so I checked : installing the Facebook App and it wasn't working anymore, deleting it, it worked fine then no issue. So here my question : Why is that and how to fix it when Facebook Official App is already installed in device ?

Comment: how is anybody meant to help without seeing your code?

Comment: The only code I have is samples provided by facebook with the sdk and those samples : https://github.com/fbsamples/android-3.0-howtos

Comment: Is your facebook app updated?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not added key hash to app dashboard or it is invalid. To properly handle Facebook Login using the Facebook for Android app you will have to add valid key hash to the app dashboard. Have a look at this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/

check 'App Dashboard Configuration' and 'Troubleshooting' sections.